# Почему появляются прочерки в таблице SQL

Tags: sql

Таблица от oracle, вот запрос SQL:

```
select department_id, count(job_id) as count_person,
sum(salary) as salary_per_department
from HR.EMPLOYEES group by department_id
```

Вот что вернул, откуда прочерк, если в таблице их нет?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Значит есть такой `department_id`. Сделайте `SELECT DISTINCT department_id FROM HR.EMPLOYEES ORDER BY department_id`

Comment: Хм и правда есть поле со значением -, но при этом обладающим полям зарплата и прочее)

Comment: обратите еще внимание, что в потенциально числовом поле у вас явно тип varchar. Что также значит, что связей (внешнего ключа) с таблицей departments у вас либо нет, либо там тоже varchar столбец

Comment: Таблица не моя, созданная Oracle для изучения SQL, теперь буду знать, спасибо